# move elements inside associative array javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative

I have an associative array

```
var values={123:object1, 234:object2, 345:object3};
```

I need to swap 2 & 3rd one so the array looks like this:

```
var values={123:object1, 345:object3, 234:object2};
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @tymeJV - In JavaScript, objects are associative arrays.

Comment: you can't order that, what do you wanna do with an ordered "array". There may be an other solution.